# \newcommand for quadratic formula

Tags: math-mode

I am looking to create a `\newcommand` to type in the quadratic formula by using the alias `\qf` as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\qf}{x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}
```

However, when I compile, it spits out errors such as `Missing $ inserted`?  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Use as `$\qf$`, if in text mode.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that you write in a LaTeX file `since you have x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}, then`. You get an error message if you try to compile it, right? That's because you should have written `since you have $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, then` instead. So, either define

```
\newcommand*{\qf}{$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$}
```

or else keep your definition and use it as `since you have $\qf$, then`.